# SoapUI to calculate the time taken to get the response of a RESTful Webservice

Tags: web-services, rest, groovy, response, soapui

I am new to SoapUI and wanted to calculate the time elapsed from the start of the request to the end of the response of a REST Webservice. Is there any way to do using SoapUI?

Comment: Did you try the solution, Juhi?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to do that using [assertions](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/getting-started-with-assertions.html), to name it exactly called [`Script Assertion`](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/using-script-assertions.html).

Assuming that you have created a test suite, then a test case and added your test step in the soapui project. Otherwise, refer documentation [here](https://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/structuring-and-running-tests.html)

Create `Script Assertion` for that REST request test step with below message.

```
log.info "Response time: ${messageExchange.timeTaken} ms"
```

It is also possible if you want to test / meet some Service Level Agreements on response time using `Response SLA` assertions which allows you to configure the agreeable time in Milli seconds.